# Passage of values ​between pages razor, asp.net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

'm doing a page with asp.net 2.2 and c #. I have 3 pages Razor. One with a form and two others, one with a search engine and another with an activity search engine. Using a button from the form redirected to the other two. What I am not able to do is pass the values ​​(through a selection button) name and age of the personnel page and the same with the activity and the number of hours per week. Both the staff and the activities are simple classes that bring the database data sql (for this I have no problems). I tried to pass the ID with:

```
<a asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-page="Formulario" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Selecionar</a>
```

Comment: How do I get that value to be able to use it, and especially how can I consolidate it so that it is not deleted when I receive another data from the other view?
Thank you

Comment: You can add the values to your page's route template and use model binding to retrieve them. Read about Route Data: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-data and Model Binding in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: @RahulSharma There are no controllers or views in Razor Pages

Comment: @MikeBrind Ohh I am sorry. My understanding was that the form is submitted to a `Controller` action method and based on that the redirection could be done with the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways...

**1. URL Segments:**

```
www.mydomain.tld/mypage/myparam
```

In the code of mypage:

```
var myparam= Request.Url.Segments[3];
```

**2. URL Parameter**

```
www.mydomain.tdl/mypage/?urlparam=myparam
```

In the code of mypage:

```
var myparam = Request.Params["urlparam"];
```

**3. Session Variables**

```
Session["myparam"]=myparam
```

every other page:

```
myparam= Session["myparam"]
```

Comment: The first two options don't exist in Razor Pages, and Session doesn't work as you have described in .NET Core.

Comment: I use all three on a razor website projekt in visual studio

Comment: I suspect that you use them in an _ASP.NET Web Pages_ application. Razor Pages is a new development framework that was introduced as part of .NET Core. Problem is that Web Pages are added by choosing the Web Page (Razor v3) option in Add New item.  MS have managed to confuse a lot of people with their naming choices.

Comment: @MikeBrind: Nope. The other Mike is correct. You can utilize both URL segments and query string params with Razor Pages. Though, I will say, you're probably right that he's using Web Pages, and so is really only accidentally correct.

Comment: @MikeBrind: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-a-page-route

Comment: @ChrisPratt I think you've misread what I was saying. There is no `Request.Url.Segments[...]` or `Request.Params[...]` in ASP.NET Core (as far as I know, anyway - although I am always open to being corrected). Maybe I should have been clearer.

Comment: Those specific things do not exist anymore, true. Though `Request.Params` really just got renamed to `Request.Query`. However, you can directly bind data from either the route or the query string in a Razor Page, so I'm not sure of the ultimate point you're trying to make.

Comment: @ChrisPratt My point was simply that the code supplied in the answer cannot be used in a Razor Pages app because those methods of accessing parts of the URL don't exist in .NET Core. I never suggested that it is not possible to access parts of the URL directly to extract values. I'm not sure how I gave that impression.